# What's Go's equivalent of argv[0]?

Tags: go

How can I get my own program's name at runtime? What's Go's equivalent of C/C++'s argv[0]? To me it is useful to generate the usage with the right name.

Update: added some code.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func usage() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "usage: myprog [inputfile]\n")
    flag.PrintDefaults()
    os.Exit(2)
}

func main() {
    flag.Usage = usage
    flag.Parse()

    args := flag.Args()
    if len(args) < 1 {
        fmt.Println("Input file is missing.");
        os.Exit(1);
    }
    fmt.Printf("opening %s\n", args[0]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of detecting the length of `flag.Args()` here you could use [`flag.NArg()`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#NArg)

Comment: The right answer is `os.Args[]`, not `flag.Args()`. The flag package is for parsing command line arguments like `-this -that`, and `flag.Args()` returns the remaining arguments that aren't parsed. Here's an example: http://play.golang.org/p/_YtTcqLWnl

Comment: A usage statement is not an error message.  Either print a simple error message and exit non-zero, or print a usage statement and exit zero.  Never print a usage statement in response to an error.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```
import "os"
os.Args[0] // name of the command that it is running as
os.Args[1] // first command line parameter, ...
```

Arguments are exposed in the `os` package http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables

If you're going to do argument handling, the `flag` package http://golang.org/pkg/flag is the preferred way. Specifically for your case `flag.Usage`

Update for the example you gave:

```
func usage() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "usage: %s [inputfile]\n", os.Args[0])
    flag.PrintDefaults()
    os.Exit(2)
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get it in flag and didn't know os has that information. Thanks.

Comment: warning - do not use this technique if you are invoking a program via "go run", you will get the autogenerated a.out.

Comment: @bradclawsie you get a.out because that's the name of the executable, the behavior is still correct.

Answer (score 23):

use `os.Args[0]` from the [os](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables) package

```
package main
import "os"
func main() {
    println("I am ", os.Args[0])
}
```